# Filter results using findAll in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, search, beautifulsoup, findall

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

result = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-south-scotland-12380537")
html=result.read()
soup= BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.html.head.title

print soup.findAll('div', attrs={ "class" : "story-body"})
```

Problem seems to be that the info I want is in story-body but it is at the very bottom. So i end up getting loads of junk info right up until I get there.

```
print soup.findAll('p', attrs={ 'class' : "introduction"})
```

Only gets me the first `<p>` there are 8 more to collect in this example

So looking to collect in from the start of introduction to the end of story-body... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In terms of CSS selectors, you want to select all the `p` elements within `.story-body`:

```
print soup.select('.story-body p')
```

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=select#css-selectors

Comment: ..you're not using Beautiful Soup 4, are you?

Comment: No not in this example, thinking i'll move onto it tomorrow

Comment: You should. For new code, there are few reasons not to upgrade.